# Using an instance method or a function with conditional logic based on type

Tags: python, abstract-class

I'm developing a data pipeline in Python. We receive a variety of different types of data set that we need to process (e.g. xml, json, csv and some Excel workbooks) - where processing involves parsing the data into a usable structure, some data cleaning, removing some sensitive info, and uploading the output to cloud storage.

The set up has an abstract base class that sets out the required methods. There are quite a lot of concrete classes that inherit from it - even within each file type there is a lot of variation in how the data is structured.

One of the abstract methods is to write out the data to files. Compared to the data cleaning methods there is much less variation in this method - one variant for each of the types of file the pipeline processes.

At the moment this is a method defined in the class implemented for each file type, but given that there can only be a handful of options for what file format to write to (basically three options: json, xml and csv) I thought it would be easier to just use a function with a `match case`, rather than attach a method to each class.

This does, however, introduce an extra conditional check in the program that wasn't there before, so I don't know if it's right to refactor it out.

Any advice on which is the better option would be appreciated.

Comment: Python makes it really easy to just define yourself a `JSONWriter`, `XMLWriter`, and `CSVWriter`. What's holding you back?

Answer (score 2):

## Intro

If I'm understanding you right, you have a base class with 3 "write" methods:

```
class BaseClass(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def required_method_1(self):  # some number of required methods
        pass
    
    def write_json(self):
        #implementation

    def write_xml(self):
        #implementation

    def write_csv(self):
        #implementation
```

and then the individual concrete classes just call `super().write_*()` and have "hardcoded" to call the correct output method.

## Your suggestion

The proposed suggestion is to use a `match case`. It seems you mean that the base class should just have one `write` method, and then check how to write.

```
def write(self, filetype: str):
    match filetype:
        case "json":
            #write to json
        case "xml":
            #write to xml
        case "csv":
            #write to csv
        case _:
            raise UnrecognizedFileType
```

### Pros:

- all `write` calls go through a common function, so common concerns such as logging, sending notifications, etc. can be defined in the common function.

### Cons:

- behaviour is now embedded in a string (filetype parameter), so we have lost type-safety. Even if you are not using `mypy`, I think it is clear that making a decision based on a string value is a lot more error-prone than calling a function by name.

  - Everything is a tradeoff. The safety comes at the expense of flexibility, but here, it seems that flexibility would not gain much.
- relatedly, we had to introduce an exception class because type-errors have now become runtime errors and we have to account for bad parameters at runtime

### My Opinion:

- The cons are too great. Giving up type safety is too much cost (in complexity). Your unsureness seems to suggest that you notice this code smell too.
- Can we still find a way to get the benefit of the "pros"?

## Suggested Solution

Credit to @Alexander for mentioning this in a comment first.

- Define `JSONWriter`, `XMLWriter`, and `CSVWriter` classes
- Accept an instance of one of these `*Writer` classes in `BaseClass`
- instantiate/pass a `*Writer` in the concrete classes' `__init__` method
- Use a singular `write` method

```
class BaseClass(ABC):

    def __init__(
        self,
        writer: Literal[JSONWriter, XMLWriter, CSVWriter],  # or writer: Writer (some base class for the writer types)
    ):
        self.writer = writer

    # abstractmethods etc.

    def write(self):
        # common logging, notifications, etc.
        self.writer.write()

class ConcreteClass(BaseClass):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(JSONWriter())  # Or have the writer also be passed in. eg. use DI
```

### Pros:

- Still have a common `write` method that can contain common business concerns
- There was not much info in the question about what the "processing" steps look like, but you'll probably start to see that more and more of the "processing algorithm" can be defined in the base class, while the details are pushed down into the concrete classes. example:

  - `ConcreteClass` can now choose its `*Writer` class at instantiation-time, so it no longer needs to call a `write_*` method somewhere in the middle of processing
  - so: where is `write` called from? Can it be called in `BaseClass` now?
- type-safety/editor-checking: All behavior is based on well-defined objects/interfaces. no more "stringly-typed" behaviour.

### Cons:

- Less flexible: If lots of flexibility is required, locking down the `ConcreteClass`es to follow the same behaviour patterns may be incorrect.

  - Personally, I think your problem domain (writing standardized filetypes) is probably unlikely to change much, and this is not really a place that would benefit from too much flexibility. Remember everything is a tradeoff.

## Final thought

I do also read that the writing to a file may be an abstract method and can be overridden/defined by individual concrete classes. I'd argue that this is an anti-pattern and should be extracted out. (The above thoughts may help with achieving this)

The processing steps ought to produce a standardized data representation (if you don't have this, work on defining that). Then, writing a standardized "in-memory" representation to a file format (JSON, XML, CSV, etc.) doesn't really depend on the initial type/state of the data set. (Depending on details, I might have thoughts about how to continue refactoring this farther, but I wouldn't want to overstep without understanding more of your situation first)

Answer (score 1):

> there can only be a handful of options for what file format to write to (basically three options: json, xml and csv) I thought it would be easier to just use a function with a match case, rather than attach a method to each class.

> This does, however, introduce an extra conditional check in the program that wasn't there before, so I don't know if it's right to refactor it out.

Your observation is correct that it introduces more logic. Regardless of size, we should always be on the lookout for reducing the nesting/branching nature of our logic.

Firstly, I want to point out that clean coding practices are guidelines that should be applied with common sense in mind. Sometimes these guidelines net you a significant benefit (often in larger codebases), sometimes it's more of a theoretical elegance with not much practical benefit (often in smaller codebases).
I cannot judge the size of your codebase, nor the business important of how much clean coding will benefit you in the long run, this is a call you have to make for yourself.

You will find that clean coding guidelines will generally tell you to avoid this kind of case logic, instead favoring an injected "serializer" object that handles the specific serialization logic for you. For the purpose of this example, I'm going to assume it's always going to be a string-based serialization format.

Specifically, your code is violating the [Open-Closed Principle](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/open-closed-principle-solid-architecture-concept-explained/) (OCP). "Closed for modification" is a fancy way of saying "you shouldn't have to continually update your case logic every time a new option is developed".

*I'm switching to C# here because I'm not a Python dev, but the core point here is language agnostic.*

The proposed solution to adhere to OCP is to inject an abstracted dependency that represents the current case, rather than forcing your class to make that decision for itself. Consider this example:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Age { get; private set; }

    public string Serialize(string serializationType)
    {
        switch(serializationType)
        {
            case "csv":
                return $"{this.Name};{this.Age}\n";
            case "xml":
                return $"<name>{this.Name}</name><age>{this.Age}</name>";
            case "json":
                return $@"{{ name: ""{this.Name}"", age: {this.Age} }}";
        }
    }
}
```

and compare it to this refactored code:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Age { get; private set; }

    public string Serialize(ISerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Add("name", this.Name);
        serializer.Add("age", this.Age);

        return serializer.Serialize();
    }
}
```

The second snippet reduces the code down to a serialization-language-agnostic process. There's a name property with [this value], there's an age property with [this value], that's all you need to know. The serializer will know how to format them. The `Person` class is only responsible for supplying the specific properties and their values.

You might balk at the idea of now needing to develop individual classes for each serialization, but consider the following:

- If you have *many* classes all serializing themselves, you have tons of repeated string formatting logic everywhere. For the purpose of a silly example, let's say the XML standard is now changed to using `(this)` instead of `<this>` to indicate properties. Consider how many changes you'd need to make to your codebase.
- You do not run the risk of certain properties being available in one serialization type and not in another (e.g. no person age in XML).
- You do not run the risk of some classes not being able to serialize themselves into a specific type, while others can (e.g. `Person` can serialize to XML but `Animal` cannot)

Is this necessary? Well, it depends on the size of your codebase. If this is a slapdash throwaway project that you've used for a short-lived reason, probably not. If this is supposed to be a long term maintainable codebase, probably yes.